# GH2 HDMI out on MX02 & Black Magic (Need for studio recording)

Tags: studio, hdmi

I have the following gear:

- 2 x Lumex GH2s
- Matrox MX02
- Black Magic Intensity
- XLR Shotgun Mic

My problem....

I have a studio where the cameras do not move, I use the HDMI out on the cameras in to the MX02 or Intensity. I am running 23.9 frames per second output from the cameras. When I use the video in Premiere Pro, the video is all jittery. I get the issue on both capture cards.

I use a studio with a white, green background however maybe I only need cheap camcorders. The audio is coming via XLR input on the MX02.

I have asked Matrox http://forum.matrox.com/mxo/viewtopic.php?p=41114#41114
I have asked GH2 forum http://www.personal-view.com/talks/discussion/6495/recording-out-of-gh2-hdmi-out-without-pressing-record-on-mx02-black-magic-intensity#Item_7

So I am stuck and I am not sure what to do to address the stutter. I have spent over 1800 for 2 gh2s.

I have also tried filters and plugins in Premiere Pro to make it smooth. but no joy...

Can anyone provide any insight into this...

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking here.  The 23.9 frame rate is most likely 23.976 which is the more accurate standard frame rate for 24fps.  This shouldn't result in a stutter.  It is possible that your computer is simply not powerful enough to play the video smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really clear what you are asking here.  The 23.9 frame rate is most likely 23.976 which is the more accurate standard frame rate for 24fps.  This shouldn't result in a stutter.  It is possible that your computer is simply not powerful enough to play the video smoothly.

Are you trying to capture from both the Intensity and the MX02 at the same time from different cameras?  This is going to put a pretty extreme load on your system's ability to store the file and will almost certainly not work without an SSD and even that might be pushing it.

Is there a particular reason you need to be capturing the input live?  If you simply want to do uncompressed capture, I would recommend recording to Black Magic HyperDecks and then syncing in post.  Alternately, if you need to be doing live editing, you could get the Black Magic Studio ATEM Production Switcher which would handle what you need.

Comment: Hello AJ, The capturing is fine, I have 2 system which are i7s with 2 ssd RAID 0. The reason for capturing out from the camera, quality and XLR audio from the MX02 input.  I am asking why is it jittery... it does not make sense. I have exported the video as mp4 and still the same... So i do not understnad what is going on??? Have i missed something.. are the GH2 no good to capture HDMI out?

Comment: Please have a look at this video... 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmYKFCD_vwc

It shows what I am on about regarding the judder

Comment: That appears to be a drop frame issue to me.  It might be a pan judder issue, but I don't think so based on how slow the pan is.  It really does look like a problem with the system keeping up with the uncompressed HDMI data rate.  What is your CPU usage and disk I/O like during the capture?  Am I correct that you are capturing direct to the PC live?  I guess it wouldn't hurt to also check memory usage.  Look for any kind of bottle neck.  A buddy of mine uses GH2s all the time for video and has no problems, so it is most likely something with your setup.

Comment: I would normall agree with you however. I can read an write at 400 Megabytes sustained (2 x SSD Raid 0), When capturing, CPU Usage (25%), Memussage (3.2GB (I have 12Gb in total). You stated that your friend has a GH2, does he record from the HDMI Output of the GH2. Thanks

Comment: @Arthor - hmm, that's a good question.  He may not be using the HDMI output directly normally, so it could be something specific to the HDMI port.

Comment: I stated in the post, but I do not think I was that clear... A frustrating situation. The MX02 is not a none professional system. Are there any trick on PrePro to framebled realyl well.

Comment: @Arthor - I meant the HDMI port on the camera.  I know that both the Intensity and the MXO2 are very nice pieces of hardware.  I'm personally a very long time Matrox fan having used the RTX and the RT2500 in the past.  One last thought, have you tried a different HDMI cable to see if there is anything wrong with the data rate supported by that particular HDMI cable?

Comment: Indeed I have, I have used a 1m cable HDMI 1.4v and 6 other different ones. My only next option is to look for a fix in PrePro... But I am not sure what to classify the fault as... THere was a mention of 4:2:0 which the GH2 output and it should be 4:2:2, But I am learning that stuff now...

Comment: Ok. It look like the GH2 is a not go. A mangled gamma :(... So I have to get a new camera. More money.. Just a note... Would this be ok  Panasonic AG-HMC41 ?